# My button is not showing up the list after clicking?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've created a webpage using php as "everyone.php".

Now i have `twitter bootstrap` drop down menu buttons, it's working fine as i do check as a different page but I've create a page for this menu `drop_down_menu.php`. Now i'm calling this page inside `everyone.php` using:

```
<div class=ownmenu_container">
                 <?php        
                 include './drop_down_menu.php';
                 ?>
</div>
```

But unfortunately after running this whole process, it's not showing list as i do click into the buttons, i did checked the jquery and everything then why i'm unable to open the list, can anyone please help ..?

Help would be appreciated!

Here is my `everyone.php` source code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require("conection/connect.php");
    $tag="";
    if (isset($_GET['tag']))
    $tag=$_GET['tag'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Welcome to College Management system</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="img_home_pos">
        <a href="everyone.php"><img src="images/img21.jpg" height="90" alt="Rajasthan technical university" /></a><span class="header_pos">Rajasthan Technical University</span>

        <div class="container_language">
           <?php
           include './select_lang.php';
           ?>
        </div>
    </div><br>
                                   <div class=ownmenu_container">
                            <?php        
                            include './drop_down_menu.php';
                            ?>
            </div>

        <div class="container_middle">      

            <div class="container_show_post">
                <?php
                        if($tag=="home" or $tag=="")
                            include("home.php");
                        elseif($tag=="student_entry")
                            include("Students_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="teachers_entry")
                            include("Teachers_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="score_entry")
                            include("Score_Entry.php"); 
                        elseif($tag=="subject_entry")
                            include("Subject_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="faculties_entry")
                            include("Faculties_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="susers_entry")
                            include("Users_Entry.php"); 
                        elseif($tag=="view_students")
                            include("View_Students.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_teachers")
                            include("View_Teachers.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_subjects")
                            include("View_Subjects.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_scores")
                            include("View_Scores.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_users")
                            include("View_Users.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_faculties")
                            include("View_Faculties.php");
                        elseif($tag=="location_entry")
                            include("Location_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="artical_entry")
                            include("Artical_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="test_score")
                            include("test_Scores .php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_location")
                            include("View_location.php");
                        elseif($tag="view_artical")
                            include("View_Articaly.php");
                            /*$tag= $_REQUEST['tag'];

                            if(empty($tag)){
                                include ("Students_Entry.php");
                            }
                            else{
                                include $tag;
                            }*/

                        ?>
                    </div>
        </div>                
    </div>

        <div class="bottom_pos">
           <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">About management</a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

as well here is my `drop_down_menu.php`:

```
<!--first button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                  Students <span class="caret"></span>                  
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=student_entry">Students Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_students">View Students</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--second button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                  Teachers <span class="caret"></span>                  
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=teachers_entry">Teachers Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_teachers">View Teachers</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--third button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>
                  Faculties <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=faculties_entry">Faculties Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_faculties">View Faculties</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--forth button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                  Subjects <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=subject_entry">Subjects Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_subjects">View Subjects</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--fifth button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  Score <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=score_entry">Score Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_scores">View Score</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--sixth button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                  Users <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=susers_entry">Users Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_users">View Users</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--seventh button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>

                  Location <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="?tag=location_entry">Location Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="?tag=view_location">View Location</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!--eaigth button-->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                  Artical <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="?tag=artical_entry">Artical Entry</a></li>
              <li><a href="?tag=view_artical">View Artical</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
                            -->
```

Comment: Does `drop_down_menu.php` exists in same folder or any other folder?

Comment: yes .. it does in same folder, in fact i could see the menu..

Comment: You don't have to load every bootstrap stylesheet multiple times.

Comment: okay, but will you show me the solution where i supposed to be as wrong ?

Comment: check your browser console. if you are getting any errors in javascript

Comment: I did checked, i couldn't find any errors.

Comment: You know you're missing an opening speech mark in this line right? `<div class=ownmenu_container">`. That could screw over your JavaScript if it is referencing that class.